# There isn’t much/any of sugar left?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> There isn’t any of sugar left
>   Or There isn’t much sugar left.

They are from a test. I can’t see how these two sentences wrong. Are they all correct?

If not(even yes), please explain me why.

Thank you!

Comment: "There isn’t any of sugar left" is incorrectly saying "any **of** sugar".

Answer (score 3):

"There isn't much sugar left"  - This is correct English.

"There isn't any of sugar left" - This is not correct.

When you use "any of" you mean "all of a particular supply".  This means you nearly always need "the"

> "There isn't any of the sugar left"

For this to be correct, you need the speaker needs to know "which sugar" you are talking about. You could, for example, supply this information in the same expression:

> There isn't any of the sugar that we bought last week left. Who has used it all up??

You can also use "some of the sugar", or "most of the sugar"  (for example) provided the listener understands which particular supply of sugar you are talking about.

Otherwise, you should say

> There isn't any sugar left.

This, of course, is different in meaning to "there isn't much sugar left".